# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate on array of subdocuments

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to replace an array of sub-documents with a new copy of the array.

Something like...

```
var products = productUrlsData;   //new array of documents

var srid = the_correct_id;

StoreRequest.findOneAndUpdate({_id: srid}, {$set: {products: products}}, {returnNewDocument : true}).then(function(sr) {
        return res.json({ sr: sr});  //is not modified
}).catch(function(err) {
        return res.json({err: err});
})
```

The products var has the correct modifications, but the returned object, as well as the document in the db, are not being modified. Is this not the correct way to replace a field which is an array of subdocuments? If not, what is?

Comment: did you try by explicitly setting multi : true? . Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: yes. no change.

Comment: @valen instead of `returnNewDocument: true`, the option should just be: `new: true`

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party plus I am really in a hurry -- but should be:

```
StoreRequest.updateOne(
        { _id: srid },
        { $set: { 'products.$': products }},
        { new: true });
```

I couldn't make it work with `findOneAndUpdate` but the above does work.